# Android custom control onClick from XML

Tags: android, custom-controls

I've created a custom controll having sublassed FrameLayout and now I need to add click handling on the control. If I simply implement OnClickListener I'll have to specify the handlers in Java code. Is there a way to attach a listener from XML just like using plain Button element?